# Websocket library for ASP.net mvc 4 and asp.net api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, websocket

i am developing a webgl + websocket based application.
i want to use websocket server and client in asp.net mvc application.

Pls tell me any good and stable websocket library available for asp.net mvc 4 and asp.net api.

i dont want to use signalr library since it can not be used to send large binary data from server to client.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ASP.NET SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr)

> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes
>   developing real-time web functionality easy. SignalR allows
>   bi-directional communication between server and client. Servers can
>   now push content to connected clients instantly as it becomes
>   available. SignalR supports Web Sockets, and falls back to other
>   compatible techniques for older browsers. SignalR includes APIs for
>   connection management (for instance, connect and disconnect events),
>   grouping connections, and authorization.
>
> **SignalR and WebSocket**
>
> SignalR uses the new WebSocket transport where available, and falls
>   back to older transports where necessary. While you could certainly
>   write your application using WebSocket directly, using SignalR means
>   that a lot of the extra functionality you would need to implement will
>   already have been done for you. Most importantly, this means that you
>   can code your application to take advantage of WebSocket without
>   having to worry about creating a separate code path for older clients.
>   SignalR also shields you from having to worry about updates to
>   WebSocket, since SignalR will continue to be updated to support
>   changes in the underlying transport, providing your application a
>   consistent interface across versions of WebSocket.
>
> While you could certainly create a solution using WebSocket alone,
>   SignalR provides all of the functionality you would need to write
>   yourself, such as fallback to other transports and revising your
>   application for updates to WebSocket implementations.

Comment: You can try using socket io.